# Passing multiple arguments to expect file with az vm extension set

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am running a series of scripts on an Azure VM with Azure DevOps. Our organization has many limitations and blockers preventing things from running smoothly so the best way for us to run configuration scripts and such on a VM is to use the "az vm extension set" command.

`az vm extension set --vm-name ${{ parameters.primary_vm }} --name CustomScript --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --version 2.0 --settings '{"fileUris": ["${{ parameters.primary_uri }}"], "commandToExecute": "sudo chmod +x ./config.exp && ./config.exp ${{ parameters.param1 }} ${{ parameters.param2 }} ${{ parameters.param3 }}"}' --protected-settings '{"storageAccountName": "${{ parameters.storage_account }}", "storageAccountKey": "${{ parameters.storage_key }}"}'`

I want to pass 3 arguments from the DevOps pipeline into the command to execute that will be passed into the expect file being ran.

`"commandToExecute": "sudo chmod +x ./config.exp && ./config.exp ${{ parameters.param1 }} ${{ parameters.param2 }} ${{ parameters.param3 }}`

But this does not work and I receive and error that the pipeline is expecting a comma delimeter.

`Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 237 (char 236)`

If I remove the two extra arguments and only pass one, the script will be run on the VM but cannot execute and will fail because of the missing arguments.

I hope I am missing something obvious here, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific use case I was actually able to wrap the arguments in single quotes to get the desired results. I realized the values being sent were causing issues with the command.

`"commandToExecute": "sudo chmod +x ./config.exp && ./config.exp '${{ parameters.param1 }}' '${{ parameters.param2 }}' '${{ parameters.param3 }}'`

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT, yes I will :)